# Recuperar dados do Banco para o Android utilizando o php!

Tags: php, android, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Preciso recuperar os dados nome,mensagem,lat,long do php. O problema está sendo na parte de Android, o que eu preciso fazer para recuperar esses dados dentre da Activity "Parte Android" salvando estes em variáveis?

Parte php:

```
$sql = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM mensagem 
         INNER JOIN usuarios ON mensagem.idUsuarios = usuarios.idUsuarios

    ");

foreach ($sql as $value) {
    //$sql = $value['mensagem'];
    echo $value['nome']; 
    echo "<br>";
    echo $value['mensagem'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $value['lat'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $value['long'];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Parte android:

```
package mundosenai.mundosenai.com.mundosenai;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
   @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Comment: O seu banco e Mysql?

Comment: @ElvisRoberto phpMyAdmin é uma gui para acesso ao banco de dados mysql

Comment: Sim foi feito em mysql.

Comment: Normalmente trabalho fazendo o php retornar um json, ai no android eu faço a leitura dele. Do modo que vc está fazendo vai ficar complicado pra ler os valores retornados.